# How to programmatically choose "board model" and "port number" in Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide, uploading, debugging, automatization

I'm testing three different Arduino (nano, Uno and Mega) each of them having a nRF module. The codes (sketches) are different for each module.
I've connected the arduinos to my single laptop via 3 USB ports.

Problem is, whenever I want to re-upload a sketch and fix a bug, I have to choose board model and port number of that sketch by using the menus. It has become frustrating using mouse each time I need to change something.
How can I set these parameters in code so each sketch knows which port and model it is related to?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do that with the Arduino IDE. You may have more luck with a Makefile-based workflow.

Comment: You can do it in UECIDE...

Answer (score 2):

You can't in the Arduino IDE, it's not designed that way (you can't even have different board/port settings in different windows - it's stored in the Java equivalent of a single global).

Instead you will have to switch to a different programming environment.

Personally (since I am the author) I would suggest switching to [UECIDE](http://uecide.org). That has far more advanced facilities than the Arduino IDE, yet still retains most of the simplicity of use.

In UECIDE you can not only have different ports and boards selected in different windows, you can also configure individual sketches to automatically select their board and port.

- **Sketch -> Sketch Properties... -> Objects tab**

  [image]

Comment: Tried to install it in Linux, but update fails: GPG error: http://majenko.co.uk/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8386A4D0CA9F00A1

Comment: You have to install "majenko-keyring" first from the same repository. It adds the public key for you.

Comment: Or you can manually download the public key and add it with `apt-key add`: http://majenko.co.uk/debian/key.asc

Comment: Just following the script: First, update. Update failed. So, next install also failed:  "Unable to locate package majenko-keyring".

Comment: Darn, looks like I only had that package in unstable. Just backported it to stable.

Comment: That works. I'm working in a project with a nodeMCU talking I2C with an Arduino and I really need this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61853/discussion-between-look-alterno-and-majenko).

Comment: NodeMCU support is sometimes a little shaky. The development tools provided by the ESP crowd aren't always the most stable of beasts. If you have any troubles with it head over to the UECIDE forums and I'll adjust whatever needs adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the (similar) question and answer in https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/9182/22924

It talks about multiple UNOs, but the solution should help here.